# Not outputting every value from list

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, return

When I print the results it is only printing one True/False value for each function. For dict1 and dict2 it is supposed to reiterate and return multiple values.

Current outcome is:

```
False
True
False
```

The expected outcome is:
print(fullCoverageClearance(dict1)) -> `[False, False]`

print(fullCoverageClearance(dict2)) -> `[False, True, False, True]`

print(fullCoverageClearance(dict3)) -> `[False]`

Code is as follows:

```
dict1 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}, "SK" : {"Paid": [400, 1000, 1600]}}
dict2 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}, "SK" : {"Paid": [1010, 2000]}, "MJ":{"Paid" : [5, 6, 7]}, "ZF" : {"Paid": [2660, 500]}}
dict3 = {"SK" : {"Paid" : [200, 400]}}


def fullCoverageClearance(dict1):
   total1 = [sum(dict1["JS"]["Paid"]), sum(dict3["SK"]["Paid"])]
   for i in total1:
        if i <= 3000:
            return 'False'
        else:
            return 'True'  
def fullCoverageClearance(dict2):
   total2 = [sum(dict2["JS"]["Paid"]), sum(dict2["SK"]["Paid"]), sum(dict2["MJ"]["Paid"]), sum(dict2["ZF"]["Paid"])]
   for i in total2:
        if i <= 3000:
            return 'False'
        else:
            return 'True'
def fullCoverageClearance(dict3):
    total3 = [sum(dict3["SK"]["Paid"])]
    for i in total3:
        if i <= 3000:
            return 'False'
        else:
            return 'True'

print(fullCoverageClearance(dict1))
print(fullCoverageClearance(dict2))
print(fullCoverageClearance(dict3))
```

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your code, its confusing what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe this will put you down the right path:

```
dict1 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}, "SK" : {"Paid": [400, 1000, 1600]}}

def fullCoverageClearance(vals):
   totals = [sum(vals["JS"]["Paid"]), sum(vals["SK"]["Paid"])]
   print(totals)
   results = []
   
   for amt in totals:
        print(amt)
        if amt <= 3000:
            results.append(False)
        else:
            results.append(True) 
            
   return results
            

print(fullCoverageClearance(dict1))


# Output
# [1700, 3000]
# 1700
# 3000
# [False, False]
```

A better approach is to generalize `fullCoverageClearance()` to make it re-usable

```
dict1 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}, "SK" : {"Paid": [400, 1000, 1600]}}
dict2 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}, "SK" : {"Paid": [1010, 2000]}, "MJ":{"Paid" : [5, 6, 7]}, "ZF" : {"Paid": [2660, 500]}}
dict3 = {"SK" : {"Paid" : [200, 400]}}

def getFullCoverageClearance(data):
   results = []
   
   for key, val in data.items():
      total = sum(val['Paid'])
      
      if total <= 3000:
         results.append(False)
      else:
         results.append(True) 
            
   return results
   
print(getFullCoverageClearance(dict1))
print(getFullCoverageClearance(dict2))
print(getFullCoverageClearance(dict3))

# Output
# [False, False]
# [False, True, False, True]
# [False]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great. Now if I wanted to change the function so that I dont need to specify the dictionary (dict1, dict2, dict3). So that the input could be just the first "JS" entry or could be all four (JS, SK, MJ, ZF). How would I write that one out?

Comment: @ncarrawa `dict1`, `dict2`, and `dict3` are dictionary types. You want to iterate through the entries in the dictionary instead of explicitly accessing the values through the keys. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the question correctly this is what you want, I didn't change the conditions which means the actual output is this:

```
[False, False]
[False, True, False, True]
[False]
```

The reason that the first output is false and false, is that the second value is exactly 3000 which evaluates the condition to true out putting a false

```
dict1 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}, "SK" : {"Paid": [400, 1000, 1600]}}
dict2 = {"JS" : {"Paid" : [200, 400, 500, 600]}, "SK" : {"Paid": [1010, 2000]}, "MJ":{"Paid" : [5, 6, 7]}, "ZF" : {"Paid": [2660, 500]}}
dict3 = {"SK" : {"Paid" : [200, 400]}}

def fullCoverageClearance1(dict1):
   total1 = [sum(dict1["JS"]["Paid"]), sum(dict1["SK"]["Paid"])]
   results = []
   for i in total1:
        if i <= 3000:
            results.append(False)
        else:
            results.append(True)
   return results


def fullCoverageClearance2(dict2):
   total2 = [sum(dict2["JS"]["Paid"]), sum(dict2["SK"]["Paid"]), sum(dict2["MJ"]["Paid"]), sum(dict2["ZF"]["Paid"])]
   results = []
   for i in total2:
       if i <= 3000:
           results.append(False)
       else:
           results.append(True)
   return results


def fullCoverageClearance3(dict3):
    total3 = [sum(dict3["SK"]["Paid"])]
    results = []
    for i in total3:
        if i <= 3000:
            results.append(False)
        else:
            results.append(True)
    return results

print(fullCoverageClearance1(dict1))
print(fullCoverageClearance2(dict2))
print(fullCoverageClearance3(dict3))
```

If you use return the whole function will just quit out and work on the next function which only outputs one value.

Also, you function names are over lapping which overrides the previous stated functions.

```
def fullCoverageClearance(dict1):
   total1 = [sum(dict1["JS"]["Paid"]), sum(dict3["SK"]["Paid"])]
   for i in total1:
        if i <= 3000:
            return 'False'
        else:
            return 'True'
```

if you look at the variable total1 second element, you see that there is a typo. Be sure that you double check you code.